# Build raw Ethereum transaction in Go - contract function call

Tags: go, blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

I'm modifying go-ethereum to be able to handle merged mining with a token we're creating. So every time a miner has our version of geth running and mining, if they find a block, they will receive X amount of our token via our contract.

The contract is built to handle giving out the reward to the miner of the block. I just need to modify go-ethereum to handle adding the transaction of calling the reward function in the contract and adding it to the tx pool before submitting the block.

In go-ethereum, I've added a new go file, `token_claim.go` in the miner package. Looking in miner.go file, it appears that I need to add in this code to build an sign the reward claim transaction in `/go-ethereum-1.6.7/miner/worker.go` around `line 474` right before sealing the block.

Can someone provide an example of building a raw transaction in Go calling a contract function. I have the abi, bytecode, and contract address.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of how you can interact with a smart contract in Go. Assuming you have `solc` and `abigen` installed.

```
solc --abi Store.sol > Store.abi
solc --bin Store.sol > Store.bin
abigen --bin=Store.bin --abi=Store.abi --pkg=store --out=Store.go
```

Store.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Store {
  event ItemSet(bytes32 key, bytes32 value);

  string public version;
  mapping (bytes32 => bytes32) public items;

  constructor(string _version) public {
    version = _version;
  }

  function setItem(bytes32 key, bytes32 value) external {
    items[key] = value;
    emit ItemSet(key, value);
  }
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"

    store "./contracts" // for demo
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rinkeby.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA("fad9c8855b740a0b7ed4c221dbad0f33a83a49cad6b3fe8d5817ac83d38b6a19")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("error casting public key to ECDSA")
    }

    fromAddress := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA)
    nonce, err := client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    gasPrice, err := client.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    auth := bind.NewKeyedTransactor(privateKey)
    auth.Nonce = big.NewInt(int64(nonce))
    auth.Value = big.NewInt(0)     // in wei
    auth.GasLimit = uint64(300000) // in units
    auth.GasPrice = gasPrice

    address := common.HexToAddress("0x147B8eb97fD247D06C4006D269c90C1908Fb5D54")
    instance, err := store.NewStore(address, client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    key := [32]byte{}
    value := [32]byte{}
    copy(key[:], []byte("foo"))
    copy(value[:], []byte("bar"))

    tx, err := instance.SetItem(auth, key, value)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("tx sent: %s", tx.Hash().Hex()) // tx sent: 0x8d490e535678e9a24360e955d75b27ad307bdfb97a1dca51d0f3035dcee3e870

    result, err := instance.Items(&bind.CallOpts{}, key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(result[:])) // "bar"
}
```

For more examples, check out the [Ethereum Development with Go book](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73430412/why-signed-tx-should-be-encoded-to-bytes-before-sending-raw-transaction) is referencing the raw tx sending part of the Ethereum Development with Go book. Possibly could you take a look in it? I don't understand why are you adding the extra byte encoding part before sending the transaction.